# NHibernate, reseting properties after accessing related object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm a novice with NHibernate and am encountering a weird behavior (using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 FluentNHibernate version 1.1.0.685). Somehow the id which is a Guid is getting reset to empty after you first access the Item object. Is there some side-effect that happens when accessing a related object as in line 2?

```
1. System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(widgetQueue.Item.Id);
2. var ItemStageId = widgetQueue.Item.CurrentStage.Id.ToString();
3. System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(widgetQueue.Item.Id);

Output Window:   
113a6af2-3fe2-49c2-9276-9ec30081a811    
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Update:

I changed the Id field from **new virtual**:

```
public class Item : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>
{
    private Guid id;

    [DomainSignature]
    public new virtual Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        protected set { id = value; }
    }
     ....
    public Item() {
         Id = Guid.Empty;
         ....
    }

    public Item(Guid id)
        : base()
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

to **override**:

```
public class Item : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>
{
    private Guid id;

    [DomainSignature]
    public override Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        protected set { id = value; }
    }
     ....
}
```

I was expecting a runtime error since I read properties need to be virtual for the lazy loading to work. Any clue what's happening?

Update 2: I noticed that we declared an instance variable to support the Id property. So, I removed it and accessed the base class' Id. This works and makes more sense, still haven't found the reasoning why the previous attempts failed.

public class Item : EntityWithTypedId
    {
        //private Guid id;

```
    [DomainSignature]
    public new virtual Guid Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
        protected set { base.Id = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post code for your widget queue and item classes? Any relevant mappings would be helpful as well.

Comment: I tinkered around a bit more and think I made some progress. I'm not sure how to show you the mappings. I'm using the Sharp Architecure framework and haven't learned how it generates models.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the latest versions of Sharp Arch., but two things strike me as strange with the code: overriding (or using *new*) the ID property, and accepting the ID using a constructor. This seems like it could lead to problems.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the proper way to use ID properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityWithTypedId does already define an Id-property, you dont have to declare that yourself.

for example in fluent mappings you can safely use the id property with:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);
```

Comment: good to know but it also get the [DomainSignature] attribute?

Comment: no, but as i understand it, `[DomainSignature]` is for natural keys not surrogate keys. the Id-Property is for persistance and using the code above, its handled by nhibernate.